# How to write unit tests in Spark 2.0+?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, junit, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to find a reasonable way to test `SparkSession` with the JUnit testing framework. While there seem to be good examples for `SparkContext`, I couldn't figure out how to get a corresponding example working for `SparkSession`, even though it is used in several places internally in [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/). I'd be happy to try a solution that doesn't use spark-testing-base as well if it isn't really the right way to go here.

Simple test case ([complete MWE project](https://github.com/bbarker/ProjectGists/tree/master/Scala/SparkSessionTester) with `build.sbt`):

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.DataFrameSuiteBase
import org.junit.Test
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


class SessionTest extends FunSuite with DataFrameSuiteBase {

  implicit val sparkImpl: SparkSession = spark

  @Test
  def simpleLookupTest {

    val homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home")
    val training = spark.read.format("libsvm")
      .load(s"$homeDir\\Documents\\GitHub\\sample_linear_regression_data.txt")
    println("completed simple lookup test")
  }

}
```

The result of running this with JUnit is an NPE at the  load line:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SessionTest.simpleLookupTest(SessionTest.scala:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Note it shouldn't matter that the file being loaded exists or not; in a properly configured SparkSession, a [more sensible error will be thrown](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20497).

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses so far; I hope to review soon. I also opened up an issue and am cross referencing it here: https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/180

Comment: Unfortunately, I still haven't gotten around to actually using Spark ... some day, maybe 3.x at this rate - otherwise I would work on accepting an answer. Glad this has been useful to others.

Answer (score 132):

Thank you for putting this outstanding question out there. For some reason, when it comes to Spark, everyone gets so caught up in the analytics that they forget about the great software engineering practices that emerged the last 15 years or so. This is why we make it a point to discuss testing and continuous integration (among other things like DevOps) in our course.

***A Quick Aside on Terminology***

A *true* unit test means you have complete control over every component in the test. There can be no interaction with databases, REST calls, file systems, or even the system clock; everything has to be "doubled" (e.g. mocked, stubbed, etc) as Gerard Mezaros puts it in [xUnit Test Patterns](http://www.gerardmeszaros.com/). I know this seems like semantics, but it really matters. Failing to understand this is one major reason why you see intermittent test failures in continuous integration.

***We Can Still Unit Test***

So given this understanding, unit testing an `RDD` is impossible. However, there is still a place for unit testing when developing analytics.

Consider a simple operation:

```
rdd.map(foo).map(bar)
```

Here `foo` and `bar` are simple functions. Those can be unit tested in the normal way, and they should be with as many corner cases as you can muster. After all, why do they care where they are getting their inputs from whether it is a test fixture or an `RDD`?

***Don't Forget the Spark Shell***

This isn't testing *per se*, but in these early stages you also should be experimenting in the Spark shell to figure out your transformations and especially the consequences of your approach. For example, you can examine physical and logical query plans, partitioning strategy and preservation, and the state of your data with many different functions like `toDebugString`, `explain`, `glom`, `show`, `printSchema`, and so on. I will let you explore those.

You can also set your master to `local[2]` in the Spark shell and in your tests to identify any problems that may only arise once you start to distribute work.

***Integration Testing with Spark***

Now for the fun stuff.

In order to *integration test* Spark after you feel confident in the quality of your helper functions and `RDD`/`DataFrame` transformation logic, it is critical to do a few things (regardless of build tool and test framework):

- Increase JVM memory.
- Enable forking but disable parallel execution.
- Use your test framework to accumulate your Spark integration tests into suites, and initialize the `SparkContext` before all tests and stop it after all tests.

With ScalaTest, you can mix in `BeforeAndAfterAll` (which I prefer generally) or `BeforeAndAfterEach`as @ShankarKoirala does to initialize and tear down Spark artifacts. I know this is a reasonable place to make an exception, but I really don't like those mutable `var`s you have to use though.

***The Loan Pattern***

Another approach is to use the [Loan Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762240/loaner-pattern-in-scala).

For example (using ScalaTest):

```
class MySpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with SparkContextSetup {
  "My analytics" should {
    "calculate the right thing" in withSparkContext { (sparkContext) =>
      val data = Seq(...)
      val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
      val total = rdd.map(...).filter(...).map(...).reduce(_ + _)

      total shouldBe 1000
    }
  }
}

trait SparkContextSetup {
  def withSparkContext(testMethod: (SparkContext) => Any) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("Spark test")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    try {
      testMethod(sparkContext)
    }
    finally sparkContext.stop()
  }
}
```

As you can see, the Loan Pattern makes use of higher-order functions to "loan" the `SparkContext` to the test and then to dispose of it after it's done.

***Suffering-Oriented Programming (Thanks, Nathan)***

It is totally a matter of preference, but I prefer to use the Loan Pattern and wire things up myself as long as I can before bringing in another framework. Aside from just trying to stay lightweight, frameworks sometimes add a lot of "magic" that makes debugging test failures hard to reason about. So I take a [Suffering-Oriented Programming](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/suffering-oriented-programming.html) approach--where I avoid adding a new framework until the pain of not having it is too much to bear. But again, this is up to you.

The best choice for that alternate framework is of course [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) as @ShankarKoirala mentioned. In that case, the test above would look like this:

```
class MySpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with SharedSparkContext {
      "My analytics" should {
        "calculate the right thing" in { 
          val data = Seq(...)
          val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
          val total = rdd.map(...).filter(...).map(...).reduce(_ + _)
    
          total shouldBe 1000
        }
      }
 }
```

Note how I didn't have to do anything to deal with the `SparkContext`. `SharedSparkContext` gave me all that--with `sc` as the `SparkContext`--for free. Personally though I wouldn't bring in this dependency for just this purpose since the Loan Pattern does exactly what I need for that. Also, with so much unpredictability that happens with distributed systems, it can be a real pain to have to trace through the magic that happens in the source code of a third-party library when things go wrong in continuous integration.

Now where *spark-testing-base* really shines is with the Hadoop-based helpers like `HDFSClusterLike` and `YARNClusterLike`. Mixing those traits in can really save you a lot of setup pain. Another place where it shines is with the [Scalacheck](https://www.scalacheck.org/)-like properties and generators--assuming of course you understand how property-based testing works and why it is useful. But again, I would personally hold off on using it until my analytics and my tests reach that level of sophistication.

***"Only a Sith deals in absolutes." -- Obi-Wan Kenobi***

Of course, you don't have to choose one or the other either. Perhaps you could use the Loan Pattern approach for most of your tests and *spark-testing-base* only for a few, more rigorous tests. The choice isn't binary; you can do both.

***Integration Testing with Spark Streaming***

Finally, I would just like to present a snippet of what a SparkStreaming integration test setup with in-memory values might look like without *spark-testing-base*:

```
val sparkContext: SparkContext = ...
val data: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(("a", "1"), ("b", "2"), ("c", "3"))
val rdd: RDD[(String, String)] = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val strings: mutable.Queue[RDD[(String, String)]] = mutable.Queue.empty[RDD[(String, String)]]
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(1))
val dStream: InputDStream = streamingContext.queueStream(strings)
strings += rdd
```

This is simpler than it looks. It really just turns a sequence of data into a queue to feed to the `DStream`. Most of it is really just boilerplate setup that works with the Spark APIs. Regardless, you can compare this with `StreamingSuiteBase` [as found in](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/StreamingSuiteBase) *spark-testing-base* to decide which you prefer.

This might be my longest post ever, so I will leave it here. I hope others chime in with other ideas to help improve the quality of our analytics with the same agile software engineering practices that have improved all other application development.

And with apologies for the shameless plug, you can check out our course [Software Engineering with Apache Spark](https://www.vidyasource.com/courses/software-engineering-with-apache-spark), where we address a lot of these ideas and more. We hope to have an online version soon.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but using the loan pattern will make you start and stop the spark context for each of the test case defined, and the only way to avoid this to use the answer provided by koiralo ?

Comment: This should be selected as the right answer to the question.

Answer (score 29):

You can write a simple test with FunSuite and BeforeAndAfterEach like below

```
class Tests extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  var sparkSession : SparkSession = _
  override def beforeEach() {
    sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("udf testings")
      .master("local")
      .config("", "")
      .getOrCreate()
  }

  test("your test name here"){
    //your unit test assert here like below
    assert("True".toLowerCase == "true")
  }

  override def afterEach() {
    sparkSession.stop()
  }
}
```

You don't need to create a functions in test you can simply write as

```
test ("test name") {//implementation and assert}
```

Holden Karau has written really nice test [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base)

You need to check out below is a simple example

```
class TestSharedSparkContext extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {

  val expectedResult = List(("a", 3),("b", 2),("c", 4))

  test("Word counts should be equal to expected") {
    verifyWordCount(Seq("c a a b a c b c c"))
  }

  def verifyWordCount(seq: Seq[String]): Unit = {
    assertResult(expectedResult)(new WordCount().transform(sc.makeRDD(seq)).collect().toList)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer.  The [spark-spec](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-spec) used a similar approach, but it was too slow when a lot of test files were added to the project.  See my answer for an alternate implementation that doesn't force the SparkSession to be stopped / started after each test file.

Comment: I like the first part of this answer too; I just wish the second example had Spark stuff in it instead of a toy assertion. Beyond that though, I would point out that the notion of performing expensive side-effecting before and/or after a suite of tests is not a new idea. As I suggest in my answer, ScalaTest has ample mechanisms for that--in this case for managing Spark artifacts-- and you can use those as you would for any other expensive fixtures. At least until the time comes where bringing in a heavier third-party framework is worth it.

Comment: On a side note, ScalaTest and specs2 (which I think does so by default) can both run tests in parallel for speed gains. Build tools can also help. But again, none of this is new.

Comment: I have edited the appropriate test example for spark-testing-base as per your suggestion. Thanks,

Answer (score 27):

Since **Spark 1.6** you could use [`SharedSparkContext`](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/v1.6.0-rc3/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/SharedSparkContext.scala) or [`SharedSQLContext`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.3/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/test/SharedSQLContext.scala) that Spark uses for its own unit tests:

```
class YourAppTest extends SharedSQLContext {

  var app: YourApp = _

  protected override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()

    app = new YourApp
  }

  protected override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
  }

  test("Your test") {
    val df = sqlContext.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

    app.run(df)
  }
```

Since **Spark 2.3** [`SharedSparkSession`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/test/SharedSparkSession.scala) is available:

```
class YourAppTest extends SharedSparkSession {

  var app: YourApp = _

  protected override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()

    app = new YourApp
  }

  protected override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
  }

  test("Your test") {
    df = spark.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

    app.run(df)
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalactic</artifactId>
  <version>SCALATEST_VERSION</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest</artifactId>
  <version>SCALATEST_VERSION</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
  <version>SPARK_VERSION</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql</artifactId>
  <version>SPARK_VERSION</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

SBT dependency:

```
"org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % SCALATEST_VERSION
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % SCALATEST_VERSION % "test"
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % SPARK_VERSION % Test classifier "tests"
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % SPARK_VERSION % Test classifier "tests"
```

In addition, you could check [test sources](https://github.com/eBay/Spark/tree/master/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark) of Spark where there is a huge set of various test suits.

**UPDATE 2:**

[Apache Spark Unit Testing Part 1 — Core Components](https://medium.com/@eugene_lopatkin/apache-spark-unit-testing-part-1-core-components-37a283b69516)

[Apache Spark Unit Testing Part 2 — Spark SQL](https://medium.com/@eugene_lopatkin/apache-spark-unit-testing-part-2-spark-sql-35c76ed592b0)

[Apache Spark Unit Testing Part 3 — Streaming](https://medium.com/@eugene_lopatkin/apache-spark-unit-testing-part-3-streaming-79af91e5d4d1)

[Apache Spark Integration Testing](https://medium.com/@eugene_lopatkin/apache-spark-integration-testing-32d9aa9860be)

[Test Driven Development of Apache Spark applications](https://eugene-lopatkin.medium.com/test-driven-development-of-apache-spark-applications-93eec83a6443)

Comment: do you know which maven package contains this class?

Comment: Of course. Both of it in `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % SPARK_VERSION % Test classifier "tests"`

Comment: For Maven `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql</artifactId>
  <version>SPARK_VERSION</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: For me it was also necessary to add _sources_ of spark-core and spark-catalyst with
`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % SPARK_VERSION withSources()`
`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % SPARK_VERSION withSources()`

Comment: Good day, Huang! What do you mean about "Cannot resolve symbol test"? Where was it happened?

Comment: Also, ensure [scalatest version matches what spark is using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274024/1080804)

Answer (score 16):

I like to create a `SparkSessionTestWrapper` trait that can be mixed in to test classes.  Shankar's approach works, but it's prohibitively slow for test suites with multiple files.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

trait SparkSessionTestWrapper {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("spark session").getOrCreate()
  }

}
```

The trait can be used as follows:

```
class DatasetSpec extends FunSpec with SparkSessionTestWrapper {

  import spark.implicits._

  describe("#count") {

    it("returns a count of all the rows in a DataFrame") {

      val sourceDF = Seq(
        ("jets"),
        ("barcelona")
      ).toDF("team")

      assert(sourceDF.count === 2)

    }

  }

}
```

Check the [spark-spec](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-spec/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/mrpowers/spark/spec/sql/DatasetSpec.scala) project for a real-life example that uses the `SparkSessionTestWrapper` approach.

**Update**

The [spark-testing-base library](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/) automatically adds the SparkSession when certain traits are mixed in to the test class (e.g. when `DataFrameSuiteBase` is mixed in, you'll have access to the SparkSession via the `spark` variable).

I created a separate testing library called [spark-fast-tests](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-fast-tests/) to give the users full control of the SparkSession when running their tests.  I don't think a test helper library should set the SparkSession.  Users should be able to start and stop their SparkSession as they see fit (I like to create one SparkSession and use it throughout the test suite run).

Here's an example of the spark-fast-tests `assertSmallDatasetEquality` method in action:

```
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.fast.tests.DatasetComparer

class DatasetSpec extends FunSpec with SparkSessionTestWrapper with DatasetComparer {

  import spark.implicits._

    it("aliases a DataFrame") {

      val sourceDF = Seq(
        ("jose"),
        ("li"),
        ("luisa")
      ).toDF("name")

      val actualDF = sourceDF.select(col("name").alias("student"))

      val expectedDF = Seq(
        ("jose"),
        ("li"),
        ("luisa")
      ).toDF("student")

      assertSmallDatasetEquality(actualDF, expectedDF)

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: In this approach how do you recommend adding `sparkSession.stop()` somewhere?

Comment: You shouldn't need to `sparkSession.stop()` @NeilBest.  The Spark Session will be shut down when the test suite finishes running.

Comment: why need not to sparkSession.stop()? as @Shankar Koirala 's answer stop the sparkSession, is this useless?

Comment: @yuxh - Shankar's answer starts and stops the Spark session after every test.  This approach works, but it's really slow because it takes a while to start a Spark session.

Comment: but he also mention  spark-testing-base , SharedSparkContext stops this context after all test cases . I don't see any code stop even after all test cases in your SparkSessionTestWrapper

Comment: @yuxh - I updated my answer to specifically discuss spark-testing-base and spark-fast-tests.  Let me know if this helps.  And yes, I never explicitly shut down the SparkSession.  I just let the program finish running and then the SparkSession gets shut down automatically.

Comment: I'm not good at scala or spark , can you tell me how SparkSession can   gets shut down automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem with below code

spark-hive dependency is added in project pom

```
class DataFrameTest extends FunSuite with DataFrameSuiteBase{
        test("test dataframe"){
        val sparkSession=spark
        import sparkSession.implicits._
        var df=sparkSession.read.format("csv").load("path/to/csv")
        //rest of the operations.
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to Unit Test using JUnit

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.junit.Assert._
import org.junit.{After, Before, _}

@Test
class SessionSparkTest {
  var spark: SparkSession = _

  @Before
  def beforeFunction(): Unit = {
    //spark = SessionSpark.getSparkSession()
    spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("App Name").master("local").getOrCreate()
    System.out.println("Before Function")
  }

  @After
  def afterFunction(): Unit = {
    spark.stop()
    System.out.println("After Function")
  }

  @Test
  def testRddCount() = {
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3))
    val count = rdd.count()
    assertTrue(3 == count)
  }

  @Test
  def testDfNotEmpty() = {
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val numDf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3)).toDF("nums")
    assertFalse(numDf.head(1).isEmpty)
  }

  @Test
  def testDfEmpty() = {
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val emptyDf = spark.sqlContext.createDataset(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Num])
    assertTrue(emptyDf.head(1).isEmpty)
  }
}

case class Num(id: Int)
```