# How should I write unit tests in Spark, for a basic data frame creation example?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm struggling to write a basic unit test for creation of a data frame, using the example text file provided with Spark, as follows.

```
class dataLoadTest extends FunSuite with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterEach {

private val master = "local[*]"
private val appName = "data_load_testing"

private var spark: SparkSession = _

override def beforeEach() {
  spark = new SparkSession.Builder().appName(appName).getOrCreate()
}

import spark.implicits._

 case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  val df = spark.sparkContext
      .textFile("/Applications/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
      .map(_.split(","))
      .map(attributes => Person(attributes(0),attributes(1).trim.toInt))
      .toDF()

  test("Creating dataframe should produce data from of correct size") {
  assert(df.count() == 3)
  assert(df.take(1).equals(Array("Michael",29)))
}

override def afterEach(): Unit = {
  spark.stop()
}
```

}

I know that the code itself works (from spark.implicits._ .... toDF()) because I have verified this in the Spark-Scala shell, but inside the test class I'm getting lots of errors; the IDE does not recognise 'import spark.implicits._, or toDF(), and therefore the tests don't run.

I am using SparkSession which automatically creates SparkConf, SparkContext and SQLContext under the hood.

My code simply uses the example code from the Spark repo.

Any ideas why this is not working? Thanks!

NB. I have already looked at the Spark unit test questions on StackOverflow, like this one: [How to write unit tests in Spark 2.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729262/how-to-write-unit-tests-in-spark-2-0)
I have used this to write the test but I'm still getting the errors.

I'm using Scala 2.11.8, and Spark 2.2.0 with SBT and IntelliJ. These dependencies are correctly included within the SBT build file. The errors on running the tests are:

Error:(29, 10) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[dataLoadTest.this.Person]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
        .toDF()

Error:(20, 20) stable identifier required, but dataLoadTest.this.spark.implicits found.
      import spark.implicits._

IntelliJ won't recognise import spark.implicits._ or the .toDF() method.

I have imported:
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterEach, FlatSpec, FunSuite, Matchers}

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here? This test basically just tests that your data have 3 rows.

Comment: However, the actual answer to your question is that the simplest way to is to add spark as dependencies and have your build tool run tests.

Comment: @Marcin I could use SBT to run the tests from the command line but actually I prefer the comfort of my IDE :-)

Comment: Then this is a question about intellij and why its sbt integration doesn't work properly, unless you have the same problem with sbt.

Comment: Hi Marcin, it's not an SBT question. I have verified that SBT is working, I just prefer to use SBT within IntelliJ. Thanks for your help though. @Ramesh_Maharjan has fixed it for me :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to assign `sqlContext` to a `val` for `implicits` to work . Since your `sparkSession` is a `var`, `implicits` won't work with it

So you need to do

```
val sQLContext = spark.sqlContext
import sQLContext.implicits._
```

Moreover you can write functions for your tests so that your test class looks as following

```
    class dataLoadTest extends FunSuite with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  private val master = "local[*]"
  private val appName = "data_load_testing"

  var spark: SparkSession = _

  override def beforeEach() {
    spark = new SparkSession.Builder().appName(appName).master(master).getOrCreate()
  }


  test("Creating dataframe should produce data from of correct size") {
    val sQLContext = spark.sqlContext
    import sQLContext.implicits._

    val df = spark.sparkContext
    .textFile("/Applications/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(attributes => Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt))
    .toDF()

    assert(df.count() == 3)
    assert(df.take(1)(0)(0).equals("Michael"))
  }

  override def afterEach() {
    spark.stop()
  }

}
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Comment: @Ramesh_Maharjan thanks for your help! Unfortunately I'm still getting the following error using your changes: Error:(32, 8) value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Person]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
      .toDF()

Comment: you need to move the case class inside the class.

Comment: @Ramesh_Maharjan thanks! Moving the case class gets rid of the .toDF() error but now I get a NPE at the val sQLContext line: java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at data_load.dataLoadTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(dataLoadTest.scala:24)
 at data_load.dataLoadTest$$anonfun$1.apply(dataLoadTest.scala:23)
 at data_load.dataLoadTest$$anonfun$1.apply(dataLoadTest.scala:23)

Comment: Sorry, but what did you change? I already added the master(master) to the SparkSession but I'm still getting the NPE :-(  Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: i have moved the case class outside and i have changed the assetions

Comment: NPE is because you are not using test function as suggested by me.

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh_Maharjan! You fixed it. Can I just ask please, why does the case class need to be outside the scope of the test object? And if you can explain the SQLContext magic, that would be useful - the Spark API describes it as "a wrapped version of this session in the form of an SQLContext, for backward compatibility". Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: you can accept my answer if it really helped you :) you can upvote too :)

Comment: case class have encoders defined and is used for row representation of a dataframe which needs to be serialized and deserialized. If its written inside another scope then it would be difficult to move around. Thats why they need to be outside scope.

Comment: @Ramesh_Maharjan strikes again!

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries for unit testing of spark, one of the mostly used is

**[spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base)**: *By Holden Karau*

This library have all with `sc` as the `SparkContext` below is a simple example

```
class TestSharedSparkContext extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {

  val expectedResult = List(("a", 3),("b", 2),("c", 4))

  test("Word counts should be equal to expected") {
    verifyWordCount(Seq("c a a b a c b c c"))
  }

  def verifyWordCount(seq: Seq[String]): Unit = {
    assertResult(expectedResult)(new WordCount().transform(sc.makeRDD(seq)).collect().toList)
  }
}
```

Here, every thing is prepared with `sc` as a `SparkContext`

Another approach is to create a `TestWrapper` and use for the multiple `testcases` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

trait TestSparkWrapper {

  lazy val sparkSession: SparkSession = 
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("spark test example ").getOrCreate()

}
```

And use this `TestWrapper` for all the `tests` with Scala-test, playing with `BeforeAndAfterAll` and `BeforeAndAfterEach`.

Hope this helps!