# Unable to run Unit tests (scalatest) on Spark-2.2.0 - Scala-2.11.8

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql, scalatest

Unable to run run scalatest with context on spark-2.2.0

StackTrace:

> An exception or error caused a run to abort: org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext.eventually(Lorg/scalatest/concurrent/PatienceConfiguration$Timeout;Lscala/Function0;Lorg/scalatest/concurrent/AbstractPatienceConfiguration$PatienceConfig;)Ljava/lang/Object; 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext.eventually(Lorg/scalatest/concurrent/PatienceConfiguration$Timeout;Lscala/Function0;Lorg/scalatest/concurrent/AbstractPatienceConfiguration$PatienceConfig;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext$class.afterEach(SharedSQLContext.scala:92)
>       at testUtils.ScalaTestWithContext1.afterEach(ScalaTestWithContext1.scala:7)
>       at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterEach$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(BeforeAndAfterEach.scala:234)

sample code:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import testUtils.ScalaTestWithContext1

  class SampLeTest extends ScalaTestWithContext1 {
  override protected def spark: SparkSession = ???

     test("test") {
        1 == 1 shouldBe true
     }
  }
```

ScalaTestWithContext1.scala

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.QueryTest
  import org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext
  import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers}

  abstract class ScalaTestWithContext extends QueryTest with SharedSQLContext with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll{}
```

build.sbt :

```
name := "test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

parallelExecution in Test := false

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.11.11" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "test" classifier 
"tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "test" classifier 
"tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % "2.2.0" % "test" classifier 
"tests",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
)
```

The class ScalaTestWithContext1 extends SharedSQLContext and all required traits.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Reduce the stacktrace a little and add some relevant code.

Comment: scalatest with sharedSQLContext is working for spark-2.1.0, I have problem with spark-2.2.0

Comment: What's `build.sbt` for the project?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. The solution that worked for me was to use version `2.2.6` of Scalatest instead of the `3.x` version. The [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.0) also shows the correct dependency in the section "Test Dependencies".

Comment: Tried that. Both the jars present in my dependencies, deleted 2.x from test dependencies. Still having same problem.

Comment: Keep the 2.2.6 dependency and delete the 3.x dependency.

Comment: Tried it. Not working. We figured out workaround not using SharedSQLContext at all. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: you can pls share your workaround.
we are trying to unit test spark jdbc and hive context related code.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly [as already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47028432/1080804), check out the `pom.xml` file in [Spark's github repository](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/pom.xml#L792) to ensure you're using the same scalatest version.

There's probably a better solution, like having `sbt` merge or override your preferred version of scalatest over Spark's, but as of Dec 2019 `Spark 2.4.4` is using `Scalatest 3.0.3`, which is fairly recent.