# How can I run ScalaTest suites in a single thread?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gradle, scalatest

The default behavior for ScalaTest is to "run different suites in parallel, but the tests of any one suite sequentially." [See ParallelTestExecution](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.ParallelTestExecution).

How do I constrain a set of Suites, maybe using a [SuiteMixin](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.SuiteMixin), to all run sequentially? This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769845/72860) says to "enable forking but disable parallel execution." How do I do this with the gradle test runner?

My use case is specifically around running a set of [SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) based integration test suites under gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [SequentialNestedSuiteExecution](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.SequentialNestedSuiteExecution).

[Sequential](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Sequential) provides a concrete implementation of it.

Comment: Looks like I need to study how nested suites work. Right now all my suites are independent stand alone suites all mixing in my TestSparkSession SuiteMixin which provides the Spark session. Was hoping I could annotate this mixin to declare these suites "sequential".

Comment: This question and answer would be more helpful, if we could add an example. The high-level example in the ScalaTest-doc is putting me in the same place as @PeterStephens -- quite lost, and on a journey to self enlightenment, without a clear way forward. In particular, where would I put the Suites that Sequential would execute, to avoid having them get executed themselves, when testing the entire project?