# How to mock sqlContext.read.parquet()?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mockito, scalatest

```
class Test{
override def execute(sqlContext: SQLContext) {
  val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.parquet(path)
}
```

How to mock sqlContext.read.parquet ? Need to read from a json and return that dummy dataframe when this is called

```
class XTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {

test("Test") {

val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("View_Persistence_Spark_Job")
  .getOrCreate()
sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

val test = new Test()
val df_from_json = sparkSession.read.option("multiline", "true").json("src/test/resources/test.json")
    val mockContext = mock[SQLContext]
        when(mockContext.read.parquet("src/test/resources/test.json")).thenReturn(df_from_json)
    test.execute(sparkSession.sqlContext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues that needs to be understood from your example.

First, you cannot concatenate calls when using mocks. Trying:

```
when(mockContext.read.parquet("src/test/resources/test.json"))
```

will always fail because the result `mockContext` does not implement the method read, therefore it will cause null reference exception. In order to solve this, we need to add another mock, which will be the result of `mockContext.read`. So this part will be:

```
val mockContext = mock[SQLContext]
val dataFrameReader = mock[DataFrameReader]

when(mockContext.read).thenReturn(dataFrameReader)
when(dataFrameReader.parquet("src/test/resources/test.json")).thenReturn(df_from_json)
```

The second thing, in order to make `test` use that mock, you need to pass it to him, and not `sparkSession.sqlContext`, which is not a mock, therefore you cannot override its behaviour.

To sum up, a complete test will be:

```
test("Test") {

  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("View_Persistence_Spark_Job")
    .getOrCreate()
  sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val test = new Test()
  val df_from_json: sql.DataFrame = sparkSession.read.option("multiline", "true").json("src/test/resources/test.json")
  val mockContext = mock[SQLContext]
  val dataFrameReader = mock[DataFrameReader]

  when(mockContext.read).thenReturn(dataFrameReader)
  when(dataFrameReader.parquet("src/test/resources/test.json")).thenReturn(df_from_json)
  test.execute(mockContext)
}
```

Comment: if we mock SQLContext, then mockContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
is throwing null pointer exception. How to handle this?

Comment: we need to add another mock for that?

Comment: @tech_geek Yes. Same as we did with `dataFrameReader` mock.

Comment: with the above method whenever I use spark.implicits in my transform function test throws error
```org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: 
You have a NullPointerException here:```
I couldnt figure out why though. If I remove implicits the error goes away.

This same problem is discussed in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539412/spark-scala-mocking-spark-implicits-for-unit-testing.

Comment: I had to instead create a `mockito.spy` of `sparkSession` and pass that.