# sbt test fails my spark testing suite while intellij test works

Tags: scala, apache-spark, testing, sbt

I am trying to test the behaviour of a class which eats and process DataFrames.

Following this previous questions: [How to write unit tests in Spark 2.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729262/how-to-write-unit-tests-in-spark-2-0) I tried to use the loan pattern to run my tests in the following way: 
I have a SparkSession provider trait:

```
/**
  * This trait allows to use spark in Unit tests
  * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729262/how-to-write-unit-tests-in-spark-2-0
 */
trait SparkSetup {

  def withSparkSession(testMethod: SparkSession => Any) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("Spark test")
    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
    try {
      testMethod(sparkSession)
    }
    // finally sparkSession.stop()
  }
}
```

Which I use in my test class:

```
class InnerNormalizationStrategySpec
  extends WordSpec
  with Matchers
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with SparkSetup {
 ...
 "A correct contact message" should {
    "be normalized without errors" in withSparkSession{ ss => {

      import ss.implicits._

      val df = ss.createDataFrame(
        ss.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq[Row](Row(validContact))),
        StructType(List(StructField("value", StringType, nullable = false))))

      val result = target.innerTransform(df)

      val collectedResult: Array[NormalizedContactHistoryMessage] = result
        .where(result.col("contact").isNotNull)
        .as[NormalizedContactHistoryMessage]
        .collect()

      collectedResult.isEmpty should be(false) // There should be something
      collectedResult.length should be(1) // There should be exactly 1 message...
      collectedResult.head.contact.isDefined should be(true) // ... of type contact.
    }}
  }
 ...
}
```

When attempting to run my tests using IntelliJ facility, all tests written in this manner works (running the Spec class at once), however, the `sbt test` command from terminal makes all the tests fail.

I thought also it was because of parallelism, so i added

```
concurrentRestrictions in Global += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)
```

in my sbt settings, but didn't work.

Here is the stack trace I receive: https://pastebin.com/LNTd3KGW

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: can you dump the error here?

Comment: Sure, let me update the question