# How to include external avro packages for Spark 2.4 into Junit?

Tags: apache-spark, junit, avro, spark-avro

I could have asked how can I avoid

```
Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4
```

I have been using the following [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769845/317027) to bootstrap my session in junit (this approach works for all my my other tests).

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("testings")
      .master("local[2]")
      .config("", "")
      .getOrCreate()
```

But when I try to read an avro file into a DF

```
final Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("avro").load(inputFilePath.toString());
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;
```

In the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-avro.html#deploying) it mentions that for spark-submit or spark-shell we should the `--package` option.

How do I include --package for junit test?

I have even included the maven dependency just to be safe

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I would like to add that the following code works in my unit-test:

```
final Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat").load(inputFilePath.toString());
```